# How to build c project mixed with some c++ code using Make?

Tags: c++, c, build, makefile

I have a `c` project which I have been building using the following `Makefile`.

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -g
LIBS= -lm
MOSEK_H= /home//work/mosek/6/tools/platform/linux32x86/h/
MSKLINKFLAGS= -lmoseknoomp -lpthread -lm
MSKLIBPATH= /home/work/mosek/6/tools/platform/linux32x86/bin/

all: learn

clean: tidy
    rm -f learn

tidy:
    rm -f *.o

learn: spl.o api.o mosek_qp_optimize.o
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) spl.o api.o -o learn \
                     $(LIBS) -L $(MSKLIBPATH) $(MSKLINKFLAGS)

spl.o: spl.c
    $(CC) -std=c99 -c $(CFLAGS) spl.c -o spl.o

mosek_qp_optimize.o: mosek_qp_optimize.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) mosek_qp_optimize.c -o mosek_qp_optimize.o -I $(MOSEK_H)

api.o: api.c api_types.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) api.c -o api.o
```

The third party c++ code I need to use comprises of `.cpp` files (`graph.cpp`, `maxflow.cpp`, `test.cpp`) and header files(`graph.h`, `block.h`). Independently I can compile the c++ project using the following and it seems to work fine.

`g++ test.cpp graph.cpp maxflow.cpp`

Now I need to  move the code in the `main()` of `test.cpp` into `api.c` of the original `c` project. Therefore, I need to compile `api.c` using `g++`.

I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -g
LIBS= -lm
MOSEK_H= /home//work/mosek/6/tools/platform/linux32x86/h/
MSKLINKFLAGS= -lmoseknoomp -lpthread -lm
MSKLIBPATH= /home/work/mosek/6/tools/platform/linux32x86/bin/
MAXFLOW_H= /home/work/maxflow/

all: learn

clean: tidy
    rm -f learn

tidy:
    rm -f *.o

learn: spl.o api.o mosek_qp_optimize.o graph.o maxflow.o
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) spl.o api.o mosek_qp_optimize.o graph.o maxflow.o -o learn \
                     $(LIBS) -L $(MSKLIBPATH) $(MSKLINKFLAGS)

spl.o: spl.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) spl.c -o spl.o

mosek_qp_optimize.o: mosek_qp_optimize.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) mosek_qp_optimize.c -o mosek_qp_optimize.o -I $(MOSEK_H)

api.o: api.cpp api_types.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) api.cpp -o api.o -I $(MAXFLOW_H)

graph.o: graph.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) graph.cpp -o graph.o -I $(MAXFLOW_H) 

maxflow.o: maxflow.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) maxflow.cpp -o maxflow.o -I $(MAXFLOW_H)
```

Any ideas, how to go about this?

Comment: You're going wrong in not telling us what the exact error is. Guessing, you forgot the `extern "C"` on some function declarations.

Comment: Link your program with `g++` i.e. `$(CXX)`

Comment: There's also a stray backslash in the "MSKLINKFLAGS=.." line.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yes, I am already doing that. If you look at the second makefile, `CC=g++`

Comment: @doomster My `main()` is written in `c`. Therefore, I don't understand why I would need to use `extern`. Moreover, I have updated the error message.

Comment: You need `extern "C"` to tell a C++ compiler that the function should get a mangled name for use from C. I still don't see the error here anywhere. Have you tried using a C++ main()? I don't think using C++ code with a C main() works because C++ needs additional startup code. That said, you don't have to define CC and CXX, at least GNU make knows these very well, and it allows overriding them in environment vars (e.g. `CFLAGS=-g make clean all`) which you prevent by hardcoding. BTW: You're not linking with mosek_qp_optimize.o anywhere but compiling it.

Comment: @doomster Thanks a lot! Using C++ `main()` and `extern` to include the `c` header files fixes the compilation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

g++ and gcc differ only in what default libraries are linked; g++ will link stdlibc++ as well as libc and libm.  Otherwise they are the same compiler; they both support C and C++ compilation. By default any file with a .c extension will be compiled as C code even if g++ is used - it does not gain C++ linkage by virtue of using g++.

Your assertion:

> Now I need to move the code in the main() of test.cpp into api.c of the original c project. Therefore, I need to compile api.c using g++.

does not follow; api.c will be compiled by the C compiler, and any C++ code it contains or references to code with C++ linkage will fail.  C++ compiled code called from C code must have C linkage.  If api.c contains C++ code, you will have to compile it as C++ code (rename it api.cpp or force by compiler switch).